# How to access data in different userhomes from a single non-root user

Tags: permissions, access-control-list, files

I have Owncloud on my server running, and it saves uploaded files unter /home/uid/files.
But Apache is running as a non-root user, and it can't access(write) the files under /home/uid/files.

What is the best way to grant Owncloud access to a subdirectory of an userhome with 700 permissions?
And how to implement it?

- ACL?
- Any NFS hack?
- Loopback mount hack?
- Anything else?

Thanks
- Boris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try: chmod(1), chown(1) or setfacl(1). With these you can specify to be able to write into that directory

example

```
chgrp -R owncloud /home/*/files
chmod -R g+w /home/*/files
```

Comment: Ou, I wrote < UID >, and it replaced this, it should be:

Comment: And what when new users are created? I think, then I shoud modify /etc/skel... This can be a good resolution

Comment: try umask and/or set right permission on your /home and it will take care of that going forward.

Comment: But it doesn't work, if /home/uid has 700 permissions - hierarchy... Then, I should change this to 701

Comment: umask should do a job, but is there a reason you having it 700? 701 seems to be easy way to go as well

Comment: No, there was no real reason to use 700 and not 701. Thx

Answer (score 0):

ACL's are a great solution here.  The two key benefits they will provide you with are being able to assign multiple permissions for multiple groups and users, and the ability to have permissions inherit from parent folders *as* files are created.

The process is different depending on which filesystem you're using, but enabling is typically just a matter of setting a flag in fstab and remounting the parition. http://nxlinuxadmin.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-set-acl-in-linux.html#.UDvVRvvYFyY 
Once you've enabled them, they are relatively easy to setup using `setcfacl` and `getfacl`